# How to view the MCBrowserViewController in the Multipeer Connectivity framework using swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, multipeer-connectivity

i have been trying to get Multipeer connectivity to work IN SWIFT 4, but i cant view the MCBrowserViewController, I’m new to swift so can anyone help? I also am aiming to make this, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-create-a-peer-to-peer-network-using-the-multipeer-connectivity-framework
So pretty much I’m aiming to make a peer to peer connection programically.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import MultipeerConnectivity
var peerID: MCPeerID!
var mcSession: MCSession!
var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()
class viewcontroller: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {


peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil,       encryptionPreference: .none)
mcSession.delegate.self

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {



    let session = MCSession(peer: peerID, 
                            securityIdentity: nil, 
                            encryptionPreference: .none)



    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
        case MCSessionState.connected:
            print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case MCSessionState.connecting:
            print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
        case MCSessionState.notConnected:
            print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
    }

    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        foundPeers.append(peerID)

        print(browser)
    }


    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                print("image recieved")
            }
        }
    }
    func sendImage(img: UIImage) {
        if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
            if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
                do {
                    try mcSession.send(imageData, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                    present(ac, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    }
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
    }
        func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
        }
    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
                dismiss(animated: true)
            }
    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }


    func startHosting(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
    }
    func joinSession(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", session: mcSession)
        mcBrowser.delegate = self
        present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
    }

    let vc = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))


    // your view controller here
}
let vcc = ViewController()
vcc.startHosting(action: nil)
ViewController.startHosting(vcc)

  }
}
   PlaygroundPage.current


func presentViewControllerAsSheet(_ viewController: MCBrowserViewController) {

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by table

Comment: I mean the MCBrowserViewController. I cant view it.

Comment: I keep reading this page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcbrowserviewcontroller but I don’t quite understand it,

Comment: I have given a answer try it and see whether you are getting expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting BrowserViewController because you have not declared it.
Remove MCNearbyServiceBrowser.

**Steps:**

Declare a variable of type **MCBrowserViewController**

```
  var serviceBrowser : MCBrowserViewController!
```

Then start browsing for peers

```
func startBrowsingForPeer()  {
    serviceBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: locationServiceType, session: session)

    serviceBrowser.delegate = self

}
```

Call startBrowsingForPeer() when you want to show the MCBrowserViewController

Implement **MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate** and its functions

```
extension viewcontroller : MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {
    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        serviceBrowser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

   func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        serviceBrowser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

   }

}
```

Comment: Where would i put this, i put it outside of the class, am i wrong for doing that?

Comment: I mean inside the class

Comment: First two code inside class. Extension outside class

Comment: Ok, i think i got it noe

Comment: Wait which class? I have 2

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: I did. Can you add another answer with the full thing, because then i can see the full code and understand it

Comment: What full thing

Comment: I mean like, my code + your code. So like, by that i mean like can you add another answer with the answer you gave combined with my current code

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: May you do it as soon as possible please?

Comment: If you can, send the code to me through email, here: lightning417techa@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code now. It says that in the extension, serviceBrowser has errors. It keeps correcting it to NetServiceBrowser.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import MultipeerConnectivity

var peerID: MCPeerID!
var mcSession: MCSession!
var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()





class viewcontroller: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var serviceBrowser : MCBrowserViewController!
    func startBrowsingForPeer()  {
        serviceBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-         ridleyn", session: mcSession)

          serviceBrowser.delegate.self

        }



peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil,                      encryptionPreference: .none)
mcSession.delegate.self

class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate,                  MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {



    let session = MCSession(peer: peerID, 
                              securityIdentity: nil, 
                              encryptionPreference: .none)



        func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange     state: MCSessionState) {
          switch state {
           case MCSessionState.connected:
             print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
           case MCSessionState.connecting:
                print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
       case MCSessionState.notConnected:
                print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
    }

    func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID:  MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
          foundPeers.append(peerID)

          print(browser)
}


        func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            print("image recieved")
        }
    }
}
        func sendImage(img: UIImage) {
            if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
            do {
                try mcSession.send(imageData, toPeers:                          mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
}
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
    }
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}


func startHosting(action: UIAlertAction!) {
    mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
    mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
}
func joinSession(action: UIAlertAction!) {
    let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-ridleyn", session: mcSession)
    mcBrowser.delegate = self
    present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
}

let vc = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))


// your view controller here
}


let vcc = ViewController()
vcc.startHosting(action: nil)
ViewController.startHosting(vcc)

}
}

extension viewcontroller : MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    serviceBrowser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    serviceBrowser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

}

PlaygroundPage.current
```